# Two Connections For the same DataBase EntityFrameWork Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I work on asp core web applications that have many get and update functions
i am using unit of work with entityframework core
I want to know if creating two connections for the same database
and use one for only select and the other for update, insert and delete
help to avoid locks in entityframework core

Comment: Hard to answer as we have zero context of what you are actually doing, and even if this is ASP.NET of WPF etc. But I seriously doubt that would help.

Comment: the question is edited @DavidG

Comment: You misunderstand, we need way more detail than just that. And like I said, multiple connections doesn't prevent locking.

Comment: In fact, multiple connections *increase locking and the chance of deadlocks*. EF Core if used as designed *reduces the chance of locks* because *it **doesn't even keep a connection open***. A connection is used *only* when `SaveChanges` is called or a query is executed.

Comment: `i am using unit of work with entityframework core` given the *fact* that DbContext already is a Unit-of-Work, what do you mean by that phrase? I suspect you tried to implement the "generic repository" **anti**pattern and ended up blocking your connections - which is quite a common consequence of the antipattern. Post your code, although I suspect the real solution is to remove the extras and just use EF Core as designed

Comment: In the meantime read Gunnar Peipman's [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/). The "generic repository" doesn't just increase blocking by forcing you to use long database transactions, it's actually logically wrong and your INSERT can easily perform 5 DELETEs and 42 UPDATEs

Comment: `use one for only select and the other for update,` that's how a DbContext works. It uses a *different* connection for each query and each call to `SaveChanges`, closing them immediately after use. If you open a long-running transaction though, you force it to keep its connection open until the transaction closes. Don't use an explicit transaction. You don't need it