# What is the lifetime of DbContext?

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework-core

On Startup.cs, the application establishes connection with the database.

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt=>
  opt.UseSqlLite(_config.GetCinnectionString(‘DefaultConnectionString’));
});
```

This opt object of the now established database connection is injected as options to the DataContext class-

```
public class DataContext:DbContext
{
   public DataContext(DbContextOptions options):base(options)
}
```

And further on, whenever DataContext is referred to on different classes like

```
public class SomeMethod
{
   private readonly DataContext _context;
   SomeMethod(DataContext context)
   {
     _context = context:
   }
}
```

The execution flow is -
SomeMethod=>DataContext(which gets its options object from Startup) referring to the applications session with the database.

I hope we are not establishing a new connection with the database each time we are referring to DataContext.

Would love to read the answers. And please feel free to add details/intricacies to the flow as I haven’t been able to find many answers regarding this.

Comment: *On Startup.cs, the application establishes connection with the database.* -- That's not true. It's only configuration.

Comment: Hi Gert, can you please explain the lifecycle in terms of the code snippets I provided? Where is it where we’re establishing a connection at all?Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It's just the default lifespan of the .Net DI container . It's really not hard to find such facts.

Comment: Do you wanna set timeout of the connection ? Оr you just want to read the details of the process ?

Comment: Hi Darkk, want to read the details of the process.

Comment: [DbContext in dependency injection for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#dbcontext-in-dependency-injection-for-aspnet-core)

Comment: The method docs explain that `AddDbContext` registers a scoped service. That means the service, in this case the DbContext, is created when a scope starts and disposed when it ends. In an ASP.NET Core application the scope is the HTTP request. In a Blazor Server application the scope is the user circuit, roughly the user session

Comment: The DbContext won't be entered magically in every constructor that has a `DbContext` parameter. It will be used only in the classes that are registered with DI themselves. An ASP.NET Controller is such a class. When a request is received ASP.NET Core will ask the DI to create a new controller. The DI will see that the controller requires a DbContext parameter so it will create one and pass it to the controller

Answer (score 0):

Check here everything for EF Core
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core-dbcontext.aspx

Тhe way a question is asked requires a massive answer.
Here you can see specific for timeout:
https://quick-adviser.com/what-is-the-default-timeout-in-entity-framework/

here you can read everything for the DBContext in Asp.Net
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_core/asp.net_core_dbcontext.htm

The short answer to your question is:
You can't or is not good idea (if you finds a way) making two connections to the same database by using EntityFrameWork Core.

You can read also the comments here for multiple connections [Two Connections For the same DataBase EntityFrameWork Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65024795/two-connections-for-the-same-database-entityframework-core)

Answer (score 0):

By hovering over the AddDbContext method you can see the following:
[image]

The default it's scoped.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).